Why did some Hindu gurus like Vivekananda tell people to serve humanity and do charity when it is banned in Hinduism?
Vivekananda, and several other 19th-20th century Hindu gurus, were known for how much they stressed on service to humanity and doing charity. Vivekananda said:

It is a privilege to serve mankind, for this is the worship of God. God is here, in all these human souls. He is the soul of man.

But this is a purely Christian/Islamic thing. In Hinduism, as per scriptures, only Sudras are supposed to serve other varnas, there was a strict injunction for other varnas like Brahmins to not serve other castes, otherwise they will be made outcastes.
Agni Purana 168:

Accepting money from despicable people, engaging in trade, serving sūdras are known to cause (in a brāhmaṇa) apātrahood(i.e unfit to be invited in sacred rites)

Charity to anyone apart from Veda-learned Brahmins is banned in Hinduism, saying that anybody else is 'apatreya' (unfit) for charity.
So, why do Hindu missionaries founded by modern Hindu gurus, serve everyone? Serving orphans, helping poor people is something that is found purely in Abrahamic traditions, not Hindu ones at all. In all of Ramayana, Rama only gives charity of land, slaves, etc to Brahmins, nobody else.


Charity to anyone apart from Veda-learned Brahmins is banned in Hinduism

ABSOLUTELY NON-SENSE
And I say this because

शरणागतमुद्विग्नमाक्रान्तं रिपुतस्करैः |
माभैरिति चाश्वास्य शिवलोके महीयते || दारिद्र्यार्णवनिर्मग्नं महाभूतमचेतनम् |
समुद्धृत्य यथा शक्त्या सर्वकाममवाप्नुयात् || पतिते शास्त्रसंकीर्णे शवचण्डालपक्षिणाम् |
कारुण्यात्सर्वभूतेभ्यो देयमन्नं स्वशक्तितः || अत्यल्पमपि कारुण्यात् दत्तं भवति चाक्षयम् |
तस्माद्वै सर्वभूतेषु कारुण्याद्दानमुत्तमम् || अभावे तृणभूम्यम्बुः पत्रम्मूलं फलानि च |
दत्वागताय कारुण्यात् स्वर्गं यान्ति प्रियेण वा ||
Translation: [The person who] who gives assurance saying 'Don't be afraid' to those who have sought refuge, the tensed & those afflicted by enemies & goons, enjoys in Śivaloka. Those who do their best in rehabilitiating those who have fallen into the ocean of poverty or have be afflicted by the mahābhūtas (i.e the 5 natural elements; fire, earth, water, air & ether, thereby indicating natural disasters) get all of their wishes fulfilled (by the grace of Śiva). One should do to one's best ability to donate food out of compassion to every living being, even to those who have sinned, who are born of inter-caste union, the śūdras (N.B the original text states 'the corpses' which is illogical, but the Manusmṛti does compare śūdras to be as impure as corpses), the caṇḍālas & the birds (who don't even require voluntary donation of food for sustenance). Even a little amount donated out of compassion does turn out to give unyielding merits. Hence donation out of charity to all living beings is the superior form of charity. Even while lacking (objects for donation), the person who donates (even the most simple things) like grass, soil, water, leafy vegetables & fruits to one who has arrived (seeking for charity) goes to heaven.[Śivadharmottara Purāṇa:11:68-72]

Regarding your query, the wording used in the Agni Purāṇa is शूद्रसेवन which in English is translated as 'serving the śūdras'. Serving here can mean 2 things - i) providing service &  ii) being in servitude.
Now Kamalākara Bhaṭṭa, a 17th century renowned nibandhakāra of Vārāṇasī writes in his Śūdradharmatattvaprakāśa, quoting the opinion of Śūlapāṇi, a 15th century renowned nibandhakāra of Bengal

शुद्रकर्तृकदानश्राद्धादौ अर्थप्रकाशनार्थं सर्वत्र विप्रेण मन्त्रपाठः कार्य ।
Translation: In rites like donation & śrāddha performed by śūdras, recital of the (Vaidika) mantra by the brāhmaṇa (who is officiating as the priest) to reveal its meaning is to be done.

This effectively establishes the legality of brāhmaṇas providing service to śūdras. And mind you, charity is an act of service, for the donor does act of charity to those they provide service, not to those under whom they are under servitude.
There are multiple texts which highly criticise  brāhmaṇas being under servitude of śūdras as a sign of Kaliyuga. If one desires, one can search it in texts describing the portents of Kaliyuga. In fact, servitude of brāhmaṇas to anybody other than God, guru & elders is extremely criticised. The same Agni Purāṇa states

अनृते च समुत्कर्षो राजगामि च पैशुनम् । गुरोश्चालीकनिर्बन्धः समान ब्रह्महत्यया ।।
Translation: Encouraging lawlessness, serving the monarch, back-biting, slandering the guru - these are equivalent to killing a brāhmaṇa. [Agni Purāṇa:168:25]

This, we can conclude, that by the term 'serving the śūdras, it means 'being under servitude of śūdras, not 'providing charity to śūdras.
So your insinuation about brāhmaṇas showing compassion to śūdras being forbidden in the scriptures stands null-n-void.

A few questions. 1> Is Shiva Dharmottara Purana authoritative? 2> Is, what is written in this Purana, consistent with other major  Puranas? 3> Where did you find this translation cause I couldn't find it on the internet 4> If Agni Purana forbids servitude under Sudras, how is serving them, like Ramakrishna Mission does, valid?

@SuradoeUchiha 1> Śivadharmottara Purāṇa is a complelety legitimate text. It has been quoted by Madhava (composer of the Parasaramadhaviya commentary of the Parasarasmrti) & Hemadri (composer of Caturvargacintamani). 2> You can check the other answer to see whether it is untune or not. But I can tell you a similar tone is also found in the Padma Purāṇa in the chapter praising planting trees & constructing waterbodies. 3> I found the main text at MIRI & translated it using my basic knowledge of Sanskrit. You are free to diagree with the translation.

4> Charity is always done by the privileged towards the non-privileged. An employee can't offer in charity to the boss. So prohibition of being under servitude of śūdras doesn't bars extending charity towards them. Regarding the Ramakrishna Mission, somebody has already quoted an excellent verse from the Bhagavata Purāṇa in this regard.

@অনু Brahminas generally weren't allowed to make money, so they lived off charity to get whatever work they needed be done and it was generally to gain the blessings in questions, it's like if you bless a priest. Charity to Shudras need not be given as they can do work to earn it. It is up to the indivitual if they wanna donate their money and give gifts and to whom.

I think you have a basic comprehension problem, please read the verse you  yourself quoted. It is telling Brahmins not to serve Shudras to maintain the hierarchy, which you can argue is casteist, but is not a ban on charity.
You have said "Charity to anyone apart from Veda-learned Brahmins is banned in Hinduism", from where did you get it?? If you read carefully it is telling the Brahmin will become apatra if her serves Shudra. Nothing to do with Charity.
Infact the Brahminical text Manu Smriti has a section on charity and does not mention any caste of recipient, so your claim the charity is banned is not true and seems not honest.

4.227. Let him always practise, according to his ability, with a cheerful heart, the duty of liberality, both by sacrifices and by
charitable works, if he finds a worthy recipient (for his gifts.)
4.228. If he is asked, let him always give something, be it ever so little, without grudging; for a worthy recipient will (perhaps) be
found who saves him from all (guilt).
4.229. A giver of water obtains the satisfaction (of his hunger and thirst), a giver of food imperishable happiness, a giver of sesamum
desirable offspring, a giver of a lamp a most excellent eyesight.
4.230. A giver of land obtains land, a giver of gold long life, a giver of a house most excellent mansions, a giver of silver (rupya)
exquisite beauty (rupa),
4.231. A giver of a garment a place in the world of the moon, a giver of a horse (asva) a place in the world of the Asvins, a giver of a
draught-ox great good fortune, a giver of a cow the world of the sun;
4.232. A giver of a carriage or of a bed a wife, a giver of protection supreme dominion, a giver of grain eternal bliss, a giver of the Veda
(brahman) union with Brahman;
4.233. The gift of the Veda surpasses all other gifts, water, food, cows, land, clothes, sesamum, gold, and clarified butter.
4.234. For whatever purpose (a man) bestows any gift, for that same purpose he receives (in his next birth) with due honour its (reward).
4.235. Both he who respectfully receives (a gift), and he who respectfully bestows it, go to heaven; in the contrary case (they both
fall) into hell.
Source


Yes and I believe all castes even Brahmins are supposed to give gifts, but I believe Brahmins alone are entitled to receive gifts for religious reasons, but their is no prohibition to giving charity to other Varnas.

Also, Suradoe has consistently lied it clearly states a Shudra should serve a Brahmin if he wishes to reach the heavens or improve his caste it is purely voluntary and the Brahmin is also supposed to care for him to his ability. Because Brahmins have to maintain a religious lifestyle someone who wants to live an equally pious life lives with the priest or holy man lol.

Abstention from injuring, truthfulness, abstention from unlawful appropriation, purity and control of the sense-organs,—this Manu has declared to be the sum and substance of duty for the four castes.

The meaning of all this is that no man can be respected simply on the strength of his caste; what wins respect is quality; if one is devoid of good qualities, his caste cannot come to his rescue; for if it did, then there would be no point in the prescribing of expiatory rites.

I suggest you go through the following verses to learn how Hindu scriptures view danam (translated as charity).
Liberality

1.The Gods have not ordained hunger to be our death: even to the well-fed man comes death in varied shape. The riches of the liberal
never waste away, while he who will not give finds none to comfort
him. 2 The man with food in store who, when the needy comes in
miserable case begging for bread to eat, Hardens his heart against
him-even when of old he did him service-finds not one to comfort him.
3 Bounteous is he who gives unto the beggar who comes to him in want
of food and feeble. Success attends him in the shout of battle. He
makes a friend of him in future troubles. 4 No friend is he who to his
friend and comrade who comes imploring food, will offer nothing. Let
him depart-no home is that to rest in-, and rather seek a stranger to
support him. 5 Let the rich satisfy the poor implorer, and bend his
eye upon a longer pathway. Riches come now to one, now to another, and
like the wheels of cars are ever rolling. 6 The foolish man wins food
with fruitless labour: that food -I speak the truth- shall be his
ruin. He feeds no trusty friend, no man to love him. All guilt is he
who eats with no partaker. 7 The ploughshare ploughing makes the food
that feeds us, and with its feet cuts through the path it follows.
Better the speaking than the silent Brahman: the liberal friend out
yalues him who gives not. 8 He with one foot hath far outrun the
biped, and the two-footed catches the three-footed. Four-footed
creatures come when bipeds call them, and stand and look where five
are met together. 9 The hands are both alike: their labour differs.
The yield of sister milch-kine is unequal. Twins even differ in their
strength and vigor: two, even kinsmen, differ in their bounty.

Rig Veda 10.117

Non-violence, truthfulness, freedom from anger, renunciation,
tranquility, aversion to slander, compassion to living beings, freedom
from sensuality, gentleness, modesty, steadfastness;

Gita 16.2

Various forms of sacrifices, austerities and charities are performed
without any desire for the fruits by seekers after liberation, along
with the utterance of the syllable Tat (that).

Gita 17.25

Steadfast in sacrifice (or worship), in austerity and in charity is
called Sat (good). Any action connected with these is also called Sat.

Gita 17.27

Works like sacrifice, charity and austerity should not be abandoned.
They should be performed; for sacrifice, charity and austerity are
indeed purifying for the wise.

Gita 18.5
You may object here and say that danam mentioned in the above is not saying that all people need to be served. So let me give you another quote that makes the picture clear. The quote is self explanatory.
Love of all humans

I abide in all beings as their inner-most soul. Disregarding My
presence within them, men make a show of worshiping Me through images.
If one disregards Me present in all as their soul and Lord but
ignorantly offers worship only to images, such worship is as
ineffective as a sacrificial offering made in ashes. A man who
persecutes Me residing in others, who is proud and haughty, who looks
upon God as the other – such a person will never attain to peace of
mind. If a man disregards and persecutes fellow beings, but worships
Me in images with numerous rituals and rich offerings, I am not at all
pleased with him for proffering such worship. A man should, however,
worship Me in images, side by side with discharging his duties, which
include the love of all beings, until he actually realizes My presence
in in himself and in all beings. As long as man is self-centered and
makes an absolute distinction between himself and others (without
recognising the unity of all in Me, the Inner Pervader), he will be
subject to the great fear of Death (including every form of
deprivation of self-interest). So, overcoming the separateness of a
self-centered life, one should serve all beings with gifts, honor and
love, recognizing that such service is really being rendered to Me who
reside in all beings as their innermost soul.

Srimad Bhagavata Purana III.29.21-27
I am also giving other Gita quotes that are also self explanatory.
The experience of Unity of all Existence

The man of spiritual insight, established in same-sighted-ness, sees
the Self as residing in all beings and all beings as resting in the
Self.

Gita 6.29

He who sees Me in all beings, and all beings in Me – to him I am never
lost, nor he to Me.

Gita 6.30

Established in the unity of all existence, a Yogin who serves Me
present in all beings, verily abides in Me, whatever be his mode of
life.

Gita 6.31

O Arjuna! In My view that Yogi is the best who, out of a sense of
identity with others on account of the perception of the same Atman in
all, feels their joy and suffering as his own.

Gita 6.32
You have written:
'Charity to anyone apart from Veda-learned Brahmins is banned in Hinduism, saying that anybody else is 'apatreya' (unfit) for charity.
So, why do Hindu missionaries founded by modern Hindu gurus, serve everyone? Serving orphans, helping poor people is something that is found purely in Abrahamic traditions, not Hindu ones at all. In all of Ramayana, Rama only gives charity of land, slaves, etc to Brahmins, nobody else.'
How do we deal with such verses?
I had to smile reading the word 'banned'. Let us take a look at the verse quoted below.
No discrimination

If a holy act is against the interest of other members of the society,
it should not be practiced. It is Dharma which is the source of Artha
and even of Kama.

Kurma Purana I.2.54
So if you do come across any verse that clearly discriminates against entire communities then such a verse is invalid and should be trashed according to the suggestion of Hindu scripture.
You may have the question as to why Hindus didn't simply remove the offensive verses instead of outsourcing the responsibility to the reader. The answer is that Hinduism has never had a central organization that does quality control. It expects the reader to use his judgement in reading the scripture.
A Hindu should do what he thinks is right and not blindly follow ancient texts. You might ask why instead of guidelines ancient Hindus didn’t throw out the discriminatory verses from these texts. There are at least two reasons for that. The first reason is that in the absence of printing press no text was safe from modification. A scholar copying a text can easily modify a text. The second reason is that Hinduism has no centralized organization to check errors in scriptures. Ancient Christians had the Church to select the texts that were considered to be correct and dump texts that did not reflect Christian teaching. Similarly one of the righteous Caliphs, companion of the Prophet, Uthman burnt down all variants of the Koran and commissioned a scholar to write the most authoritative version of it. Since Hindus do not have any such organization they have to look at scripture to see what it says about this issue. Hindu scriptures ask Hindus to do internal consistency checks before accepting any scriptural statement as valid. Hindu scriptural verse must survive three checks reason, conscience and no discrimination in order to be acceptable.
Reply to some comments
I am posting couple of Sri Ramakrishna quotes on scripture.

What will you achieve by mere study of scriptures? The scriptures
contain a mixture of sand and sugar as it were. It is extremely
difficult to separate the sugar from the sand. Therefore, one should
learn the essence of the scriptures from the teacher or from a sadhu.
Afterwards what does one care for books?

The Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna, Chapter 28, At the Star Theatre

One cannot get true feeling about God from the study of books. This
feeling is something very different from book-learning. Books,
scriptures, and science appear as mere dirt and straw after the
realization of God.

The Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna, Chapter 33, With Various Devotees
I have given below Swami Vivekananda's opinion about some Smriti writers.

The Smritis and the Puranas are productions of men of limited
intelligence and are full of fallacies, errors, the feelings of class
and malice. Only parts of them breathing broadness of spirit and love
are acceptable, the rest are to be rejected. The Upanishads and the
Gita are the true scriptures.

The Complete Works of Swami Vivekananda/Volume 6/Epistles - Second Series/CXXIV Sir
'How can you include non-discrimination as one of the backbone of Hinduism. The very notion of non-discrimination & absolute equality of all humanity was formulated in 1789 by non-Hindus & wasn't accepted globally before 1991, while most religions, including Hinduism predate this concept by many centuries. How can you state that the Hindu religion, which is atleast 35 centuries, bend itself to novel ideologies imposed upon it by non-believers ? This reeks of white superiority.'
ANSWER: The Kurma Purana quote given above clearly asks Hindus not to discriminate against any community. This was written long before 1991.Nondiscrimination does not imply absolute equality. Hinduism does not say that all people are equal. That is demonstrably false. People are different in ability, strength, intelligence, looks etc. Hinduism only asks for non-discrimination.
'you can see how close minded and anti-modern and anti-reform conservative Hindus can be. I have talked with conservative Hindus and they are not very open minded like you or some urban Hindus.'
ANSWER: What has my position got to do with conservative Hindus with closed minds? I have my opinion which is backed by Hindu scripture and greats like Sri Ramakrishna and Swami Vivekananda. Conservative Hindus have their own opinion. I write my posts according to my leanings. They write their posts according to their understanding. Don't claim that the conservative Hindu opinion is the only way to understand Sanatana Dharma.
'"Reflecting on the entire teaching do as you think fit." - I mean my dad also, after giving a 5 hour lecture, tells me "Ja bujhis tai kor!" and goes back to watching the news. He doesn't really mean it. Similarly, I don't think Krishna meant that seriously'
ANSWER: Basically you are claiming that one of the prasthana traya texts of Vedanta has non-serious verses. Sorry if I don't take your opinion seriously.

"It expects the reader to use his judgement in reading the scripture." - I have heard this a lot of times, but never seen it uttered by any saint or guru. Pretty much all gurus say scriptures should be strictly followed, like Nischalananda and Chandrasekhar Swami

How are the verses of Srimad Bhagavatam consistent with the concepts of patreya and apatreya?

I have seen multiple places where equality is mentioned in Hindu scriptures, yet in the very next line, they are discriminatory. Like, in Manusmriti, it says a brahmin sees all beings equally yet it is the same document that treats a Brahmin raping Sudra and a Sudra raping Brahmin differently

Any verse in scripture that is discriminatory is invalid and should not be practiced according to Hindu scripture.

Manu Smriti is not saying that scripture must be strictly followed. Gita 18.63 says '..Reflecting on the entire teaching do as you think fit.'  Sri Ramakrishna says in many places that there are many errors in scriptures.

I haven't heard about the concepts of patreya and apatreya. Srimad Bhagavatam says: An intelligent man should seek the essential teachings of all scriptural texts of varying importance, just as a honey-bee sucks the essence of all flowers. Srimad Bhagavata Purana XI.8.10.  It is not saying that every word in scripture needs to be strictly followed.

'Hindu scriptural verse must survive three checks reason, conscience and no discrimination in order to be acceptable'. How can you include non-discrimination as one of the backbone of Hinduism. The very notion of non-discrimination & absolute equality of all humanity was formulated in 1789 by non-Hindus & wasn't accepted globally before 1991, while most religions, including Hinduism predate this concept by many centuries. How can you state that the Hindu religion, which is atleast 35 centuries, bend itself to novel ideologies imposed upon it by non-believers ? This reeks of white sueriority.


Sri Ramakrishna says in many places that there are many errors in scriptures

Can you cite any source?

@PradipGangopadhyay as Anu said, you can see how close minded and anti-modern and anti-reform conservative Hindus can be. I have talked with conservative Hindus and they are not very open minded like you or some urban Hindus.

"Reflecting on the entire teaching do as you think fit." - I mean my dad also, after giving a 5 hour lecture, tells me "Ja bujhis tai kor!" and goes back to watching the news. He doesn't really mean it. Similarly, I don't think Krishna meant that seriously

@অনু well, the 'non-believers' had superior technology and much better administration that we had. Also, their ideas were genuinely good, so we adopted it, like most sane human beings :-)

Good that you differentiate between non-discrimination & absolute equality but I don't see you clarifying between them. And I do also come from a Ramakrishna Mission background & I remember a line from the Kathamrta where He states that the Motion of caste distinction falls off at the highest state of God-realisation like how the flesh of a coconut which can be separated from its husk only after maturing enough & any attempts to forcibly remove caste distinction is as harmful as prematurely removing the bandage off the site of wound.

@SuradoeUchiha If you think that I am close-minded, anti modern & anti reform, then you are living in a fool's paradise. Neither do I indulge in dehumanizing lower-caste people like Swami Nischalananda Saraswati nor do I support consummation of child-marriage & satidaha like a particular user of this forum. And regarding your 2nd comment, I don't support your blind adoration of the white-skinned mlecchas at the cost of denigrating the sacred civilizational ethos. Regarding material prosperity of non-believers, I suggest you read this https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/57441/22857

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
